# SSLv2 client getting TCP RST from stud

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2

At least I think stud is the culprit.

My server setup is stud -> haproxy -> nginx -> express server

Requests don't make it through to haproxy.

I make a request with SSLv2:

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("my-server.com")
c.request("GET", "/foo/bar")
response = c.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
```

... and get back

```
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Here's the SSL dump:

```
New TCP connection #1: clientIP(29779) <-> my-server.com(443)
1 1  0.0044 (0.0044)  C>S SSLv2 compatible client hello
  Version 3.1 
  cipher suites
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  
  Unknown value 0x9a  
  Unknown value 0x99  
  Unknown value 0x96  
  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA  
  TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5  
  Unknown value 0xff  
1    0.0047 (0.0002)  S>C  TCP RST
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get stud to accept SSLv2 requests?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't sslv2 to be avoided no matter what? I would say it is good that this attempt is denied

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, but it's out of my control. A partner wants to connect with it.

Comment: Are you providing your services on the Internet ? If yes go to your superiors and get their support because it is negligent to run sslv2. You are risking both service and reputation.

Comment: Google doesn't seem to mind if clients connect with sslv2. Replace my-server.com with google.com and we get an HTTP response. This leads me to believe that it's safe enough? Regardless of whether that's true, does anyone know how to do what Google is doing here?

Comment: That hello is in SSLv2 *format*, but indicates *protocols* up to TLSv1.0 (wire 3.1); note 'compatible'. SSLv2 has long been unacceptable and SSLv3 has been for about a year (POODLE), but TLSv1.0 is still acceptable, barely, most places. I don't know what stud does or even is, but haproxy and nginx both use OpenSSL which can handle v2 hello depending on the app code/configuration.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what SSLv2 compatible means @dave_thompson_085. Stud is a network proxy that terminates TLS/SSL connections and forwards the unencrypted traffic to some backend. It uses OpenSSL, so I'm wondering if my problem is even related to SSL now. The TCP reset could be happening for another reason.

Comment: RST *could* have other causes. If you didn't trace at or near the server, do so to determine if the RST is actually coming from the server. If somewhere else, that's a different question. If so, and stud has any relevant log(s) look there.

Comment: It's definitely Stud that was misbehaving. I switched to terminating SSL at HAProxy and we can handle that client hello nicely now.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the `haproxy` doesn't support SSLv2, but even if it did it, is practically certain that the target server won't support it either.

Your requirement is 20 years out of date. Java for example has *never* supported SSLv2, except in the IBM JVM, and I doubt that it still does there.

Educate the client.